# value in input field to remain as user types

Tags: jquery, forms

I am creating a input form, and i know how to do onfocus onblur placeholder stuff etc etc..

aside from layering a div on top of my input field, this is what I want to do..

When user clicks in the input field ( in this instance to type in a website address )

How can I make it so that http:// appears in the input field, and when they focus on the field, the text prompt appears after the http://

so all that they do is type in the remainder of the website URL.

example:
[image]

```
   <fieldset>
     <input type="text" class="requiredField" name="websitename" value="http://" onfocus="if(this.value=='http://')this.value='';" onblur=  "if(this.value=='')this.value='http://';"/>
   </fieldset>
```

From the example above, the http:// appears in the input element. But on click, it disappears. What I wanna do, is the prompt appears AFTER the http:// so thy can  type their website address.

Perhaps jQuery could fix this, its hard to know what to search for on google to get some ideas.

I am sure I have seen sites implement this. I dont just want an image, because on submit, I still want it to parse the full URL and not just the www.fsfsdfsfsd.com bit that they actually typed in.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value and reinsert the value.

```
$('input[name="websitename"]').focus(function() {
    var theVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(theVal);
});
```

Sorry, EDITED. Forgot the closing parenthesis.

EDIT 2: Part of the problem you might be seeing is the fact that you have onfocus and onblur on your input, and the onfocus is clearing out the existing value. Remove that and try my script.

Comment: hmm.. perhaps i didnt explain, i want http:// to be in the input element when user clicks into it, the text prompt appears AFTER the http:// so that they just type www.whatever , im not sure what you are stating will do this. Thanks anyway

Comment: I've used this method for text cleaning (removing unwanted characters), typically bound to a keyup. I actually had to modify my own code to prevent the cursor from jumping to the end so that arrow keys worked for editing purposes. When you grab the value and reinsert it, you are moving the cursor to the end. Alternately, you could add the value 'http://' back into the input field manually, making it so you don't have to have the value set in the html.

Comment: added example image, is this what your script will do ? If I make a quick fiddle, are you happy to add your code ?

Comment: Ahh gottya , spot on . Voted and chosen as best answer pmsl ( of 1 ) works a treat mate thankyou.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly all you need to do is remove the `onfocus` and `onblur` event handlers. In this case you don't want them as you always set the `input`'s value to `http://`. There's no point in using a placeholder *and* a default value at the same time.

BTW: A better way to do placeholders is to use the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input type="url" name="website" placeholder="Your website">
```

Comment: lol cheers, why would i use both at the same time ? thanks anyway

Comment: on focus, any placeholder text is removed.

Comment: That's how the `placeholder` attribute works (and _should_ work). That's also how your current code works (with `onfocus` and `onblur`). If you always want the `input` to contain `http://` you should just use the `value` attribute and skip `placeholder`, `onfocus` and `onblur`.